# Override paint(graphics g) Java

Tags: java, swing, paint, paintcomponent, undo

I have a little issue with my GUI in NetBeans.  I draw images (dots) when a user clics in a JPanel at the mouse clic location.  This part works just fine.  I store each image locations in two different ArrayList that contains the X location and Y location.  Now what I want to do is to delete the latest image drawn in the Panel after a button is clicked.  So what I did is remove the last index of both ArrayList, and then call repaint() to draw all the images from the locations in both X and Y ArrayList (code below).

What is weird is that I need to resize the GUI (put it in full screen or just change its' size) in order for the drawn images to show up again in the JPanel otherwise, the panel remains empty.

Here's the parts of code that are affected :

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {

    super.paint(g);
    for(int i=0;i<=listePointsX.size()-1;i++) {
        try{
            BufferedImage icon = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/myimage.png"));
            Graphics graphe = jPanel1.getGraphics();
            graphe.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            graphe.drawImage(icon, this.listePointsX.get(i),this.listePointsY.get(i), rootPane);
        }catch(Exception e1){

        }
    }

private void jButtonUndoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    if(listePointsX.size()>0){
        int lastObject= listePointsX.size();
        listePointsX.remove(lastObject-1);
        listePointsY.remove(lastObject-1);
        jPanel1.repaint();         
    }
    else{

    }


}
```

Any idea what I need to do to some kind of "refresh" the whole thing?  Am I doing something wrong?  Tried searching about that but did not find anyting...

Comment: Good lord, you're repeatedly reading in an image file multiple times within a paint method, a method that needs to be blindingly fast. Never do this once, much less multiple times. Next, you shouldn't be overriding paint but rather paintComponent, you should never have empty catch blocks, ... so many things wrong here. Please stop, read the tutorials first, because you're just guessing and making lots of wrong guesses.

Comment: Yeah, what Hovercraft said.  Move the ImageIO.read() call outside of your for loop so that you only do it once.

Comment: @Parappa: not only should the image read be outside of the loop, it should go outside of **all** painting methods. The speed of the painting method is a major determinant in the perceived responsiveness of a GUI program, and this should never be slowed by file I/O like in the code above.

Comment: @Hovercraft : I know the Catch block is empty I just didn't do this yet but I sure won't leave it empty lol.

Comment: For the ImageIO.read(), like you said, it is not something that changes so I won't leave it in the loop...neither in the paint method, will just be a static class variable.

Comment: @FidelCasto: again don't do it in a painting method. Do it in a constructor, or some other code location that gets called once only. Store the image in a variable and **use** it in a painting method. Edit: and use static variables very sparingly since once a variable or method becomes static, it becomes non-OOP, and this can unnecessarily increase the complexity of your code.

Comment: What's jPanel1? You should be overriding *the panel's* paint method.

Comment: In fact, I decided to remove the image completely.  I use drawOval instead since I will need to repaint to another color later on...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Graphics graphe = jPanel1.getGraphics();` is NOT how painting should work, instead, you should have overriden the panel's `paintComponent` method and painted the points within in.

See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about how painting works in Swing

Instead, your panel should be doing ALL the work, managing the points in the `ArrayList` and painting them.  You parent component "might" have the ability to add or remove points if that meets your design requirements, but the core responsibility remains with the panel.

Avoid performing any long running or block operations within the `paint` methods, they should run as fast as possible.  Since the image never changes, you should simply load once (either when the class is constructed or when you first need the image) and keep using the same reference.

Comment: I will try creating a class jPanel which extends jPanel.  Then override the paintComponent methot and paint the points within it as you said.  Will post the code if it works fine.  Thanks for the reply !

Answer (score 1):

Alright it worked just fine now.  I had to do it the way you told me up here.  I created a new class that extends jPanel (below).  Then in my main Form, had to create an object of this class.  Whenever a user makes a click, it will call this Drawing class object and add an item to the ArrayList (this object manages everything regarding created points...  It looks like this :

```
public class MyDrawingClass extends JPanel {
ArrayList<Integer> arrayListPointX = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> arrayListPointY = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    try{
    BufferedImage icon = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/dot.png"));
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    if(arrayListPointX.size()<=0){
        ...
    }
    else{
        for(int i=0;i<listePointsX.size();i++){
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g.drawImage(icon, listePointsX.get(i), listePointsY.get(i), rootPane);
        }
    }
    }catch(Exception e){
        ...
    }
}
```

So if I want to "undo", let's say my object of "MyDrawingClass" is called "draw".  I can do : draw.arrayListPointX.remove(draw.arrayListPointX.size()-1); and call repaint(); to display remaining points.

Thanks for your tips appreciate it ! :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip didn't know that :)